# Resizing Teaser Images using Drupal ImageCache diminishes image quality

Tags: php, image, drupal, drupal-7

I'm resizing larger images contained in posts for my site teasers using ImageCache (Drupal 7), and for some reason the quality of the images goes down significantly when I size down (e.g. 670x400 pixel image is sized down to 220x185). Quality doesn't usually go down when sizing an image down (only when sizing up?)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to display the smaller image at the larger image dimensions? Smaller image = less data/pixels = less quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In back-end, under Configuration/Media/Image toolkit you can set the JPEG quality.
URL is:

/admin/config/media/image-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific image style (image cache) preset for the node teaser from content type `Manage display` page. e.g. `?q=admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENT_TYPE]/display/teaser`

Click the gear icon next to the image field, and choose the image style you want to apply to the content type's teaser display.